# Bus error (core dumped) when commit or pull in git

Tags: linux, git

when I'm trying to commit or pull this error `Bus error (core dumped)` occurs!

when I debug it with gdb, (`gdb git`,`run commit -a`,`where`) the result is:

```
muculus@muculus-laptop:~/www/pure/core$ gdb git
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/git...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run commit -a
Starting program: /usr/bin/git commit -a
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x00000000004e9338 in ?? ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000000004e9338 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000004ea64f in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000004b5143 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000004ada6e in ?? ()
#4  0x000000000041d29b in ?? ()
#5  0x000000000041df17 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000405634 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000404a30 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007ffff73ee76d in __libc_start_main (main=0x404980, argc=3, ubp_av=0x7fffffffe008, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdff8) at libc-start.c:226
#9  0x0000000000404e65 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007fffffffdff8 in ?? ()
#11 0x000000000000001c in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000000003 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007fffffffe34b in ?? ()
#14 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: git version? did u try to update it?

Comment: when you run it in gdb, can you get a backtrace? (`gdb git`, `run pull`, `where`)

Comment: Do you want to debug this? If not this would not be appropriate forum to resolve it.

Comment: @ablm the version is 1.7.9.5 , that I think latest version of ubuntu repository.

Comment: @ArnoutEngelen I edited my question as you mentioned

Comment: @Rohan absolutely I want to debug it!

Comment: @ArashMousavi, in that case you may want to compile git or get debug version and symbols from somewhere (I'm not sure if thats available) and post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `dmesg`. In my case this was due to a hardware error: A bad sector on sda.

Comment: Did you grep for anything specific in the dmesg?

Comment: I just scrolled through the output and there was quite a lot highlighted in red.